# Java 8 streams, find object by predicate with null checks

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects which I want to select one with a specific value but only if its null and I having a hard time doing this with java 8 streams.

```
String id = invoice.getDeliveries().stream().filter(delivery -> delivery.getName().equals("ABC")).findFirst().orElse(null).getId;
```

This code does not work when for example `getName()` returns null because then `.getId` will throw an exception.

How can I write this so that the value of id will just become null if ABC is null or does not exist?

Comment: Do you mean "I want to select one with a specific value but only if it is **not** null?

Comment: `... .filter(delivery -> "ABC".equals(delivery.getName())).findFirst().map(a -> a.getId).orElse(null)`

Comment: When `getName()` returns `null`, the attempt to invoke `equals` will throw a `NullPointerException`. The attempt to access `getId` will throw a `NullPointerException` when no match has been found, as requested explicitly via `.orElse(null).getId`

Answer (score 0):

Not a java expert, but maybe this works:

```
Delivery delivery = invoice.getDeliveries().stream().filter(delivery -> delivery.getName().equals("ABC")).findFirst().orElse(null);
String id = delivery == null ? null : delivery.getId;
```

Comment: Ah yes that works but I would like a onliner for this :)

Comment: Not sure if it works, but in C# you can do `someNullableObject?.SomeMethod();`

Answer (score 0):

Just change `delivery.getName().equals("ABC")` with `"ABC".equals(delivery.getName())` and then check for `null`.

***P.S.** There is a good practice, to placce literals (like `ABC`) first. E.g. IntelliJ IDEA inspections check this.*